# laravel 5.5 - reset password email sent but gmail did not get anything

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, gmail

I am testing with the build in function of `Forgot Your Password`. I send my `smtp` in the `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.example.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=email@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=Example_Password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I tried it with my production server and got the message:

> We have e-mailed your password reset link!

and no error in the console.

However, `gmail` did not get anything. I have been trying for many successful mail from `laravel` but `gmail` did not get a single one. Not even in the `Spam Folder`.

What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about setting hostname,username and password correctly?If yes run again :

> php artisan serve